# download file using file path stored in database in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net

I'm using VS2012 ASP.NET website, and I have an asp.net page where I upload files to a folder.

When I upload the files, it stores the path in SQL database tabel field like `~/Client_Info/text.docx` and the file itself is saved in a folder.

Now I want to download the files I have stored by displaying it in a gridview with a download link. But after a whole day searching I cannot get a answer. Can someone help me out?

```
protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender asLinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;

    int fileid = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString()); 
    string name, type; 

    using (SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection(strCon))     
    {

        using (SqlCommand cmd=new SqlCommand())
        {

            cmd.CommandText = "select FileName, FileType, FileData from FileInformation where Id=@Id";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", fileid);
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();     
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if(dr.Read()) 
            {
                Response.ContentType = dr["FileType"].ToString();
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
                                   "attachment;filename=\""
                                    + dr["FileName"] + "\"");

                Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["FileData"]);
                Response.End();     
            } 
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: Your code is just writing out ... whatever is stored in the [FileData] column.  However, you state that the file itself is stored on the filesystem and the database table just holds the file information?  You need to read your file from disk first, then write it to the response.

Answer (score 0):

In order to write a file to the Response you can use the `Response.WriteFile` function. It takes as a parameter the physical path of the file.

You can try the following code, assuming the file path is correct and the file exists.

```
Response.ContentType = dr["FileType"].ToString();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment;filename=\""
    + dr["FileName"].ToString() + "\"");

Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(dr["FileName"].ToString()));
Response.End();
```

Comment: Thansk for the response , I have a question , the object "dr" is decalred as an int. and it gives me an error "cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'" ow do I solve that?

Comment: The `dr` object is a `SqlDataReader`. Maybe it is a `dr["..."]` that fails to convert. I have edited my code a bit, probably this will be correct.